# Invalid syntax in Python for if statement

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.4 and stuck in the following problem:

```
age = int(raw_input("Enter your age:")


if age<30:
    print ("Are you married?")
elif age>30:
    print ("Are you not married?")
```

When I want to run it it says invalid syntax. What is the solution?

Comment: Did you forgot a parenthesis after `"Enter your age:")` ?

Comment: The first line of code misses a closing parenthesis

Comment: *"I am using Python 2.4"* - why?! 2.4.6 was released in December **2008**!

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is due to a missing closing parenthesis in your first statement:

```
age = int(raw_input("Enter your age:"))
```